# In the PayPal API, how exactly to work with Webhooks for PAYMENT.CAPTURE.COMPLETED & CHECKOUT.ORDER.APPROVED?

Tags: paypal, webhooks, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-webhooks

I am not sure I understand the difference? The way I understand it so far is that `CHECKOUT.ORDER.APPROVED` comes first and once the payment has been processed properly, it moves onto `PAYMENT.CAPTURE.COMPLETED` (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65076361/paypal-checkout-order-approved-but-no-payment-capture-completed) and [this](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/REST-APIs/Matching-CHECKOUT-ORDER-APPROVED-with-PAYMENT-CAPTURE-COMPLETED/td-p/2090889)). So there could be an approved checkout without a completed payment capture, which means, that I should wait for `PAYMENT.CAPTURE.COMPLETED` before giving users access to content behind paywalls etc.

If this is true, can I generally rely on them coming in this order (e.g. for my webhooks)?

For example: Say I create a new order in my database, when the webhook for `CHECKOUT.ORDER.APPROVED` is triggered. Now in the webhook for `PAYMENT.CAPTURE.COMPLETED` I want to continue working with this data. Can I be confident, that this order will exist in the database at this point?

Answer (score 3):

CHECKOUT.ORDER.APPROVED means a payer approved an order. It does not mean it has been captured, and any number of things could interrupt the capture. In general this event is best ignored / not subscribed to -- there is nothing useful to be done with it. Storing orders in your database before successfully capturing them is largely pointless, the order # is only useful for checkout debug purposes (not history/accounting)

PAYMENT.CAPTURE.COMPLETED indicates a transaction has been created. This is more useful. However, since it's an asynchronous notification it's generally only useful for payments that will take place in the future, such as Subscriptions. (PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED for subscriptions)

For one-time payments, there's no need for webhooks. Just use the v2/checkout/orders API and make two routes (url paths) on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order'. You could use one of the (recently deprecated) Checkout-*-SDKs for the routes' API calls to PayPal, or your own HTTPS implementation of first getting an access token and then doing the call. Both of these routes should return/output **only** JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should verify the amount was correct and store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as reserving product or sending an email) immediately *before* forwarding return JSON to the frontend caller. In the event of an error forward the JSON details of it as well, since the frontend must handle such cases.

(2023 edit: the [standard integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) has sample code for this now, in node.js but it can of course be implemented from any backend environment)

Pair those 2 routes with this frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server .  (If you need to send any additional data from the client to the server, such as an items array or selected options, add a `body` parameter to the fetch with a value that is a JSON string or object)